# How to set up a range function in a specific worksheet to get all the values from the same range

Tags: excel, vba

For example,
worksheet X has got a few values that I need to sum up. How to set up a subroutine that will check the range, get all the values from that range and sum it up.
Please note that this range is 2D (Not just a single column or a row)

I tried active worksheet function to set up a range and then for loop to parse through each cell within the range but it is throwing Run Time error 1004

Comment: Something like `WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F20"))`.

Answer (score 2):

*get all the values from that range and sum it up.*

You need to know the position of at least 1 single cell from that range.

[image]

In my example I know my data will start **always** at cell A1 and I want to sum all the values from all rows and columns so:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

> [Range.CurrentRegion property
> (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion)

Output of code:

[image]